# Nested loops pulling from lists

Tags: python, loops

I need to make a nested loop that prints a list of seats (e.g. `1a`, `3c`) based on what the user inputs for the number of rows and columns, for example an input of  `2 3` (rows columns) prints

```
1a 1b 1c
2a 2b 2c
```

The column number should be replaced with a character. I know there is a way to do this by changing the character in the loop however I wanted to get the column character from a list instead.

This is my current code:

```
num_rows = int(input('rows'))
num_cols = int(input('cols'))


a = list('abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz')
rows = 1
cols = 0
for rows in range(num_rows):
    for cols in range(num_cols):
        cols = a[num_cols]
        print('{}{}'.format(rows, cols), end=' ')
        num_cols += 1
    rows += 1

print()
```

For an input of `2 3` this code produces

```
0d 0e 0f 1g 1h 1i 1j 1k 1l
```

instead of the expected output given above.

Comment: It's little tough to connect the question to the code. Give this a read for advice on how to improve your question: stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic, especially the resources on minimal working examples.

Answer (score 2):

Too long for a comment. You have a few issues with your code.

- there is no point initialising `rows` and `cols`, as both those values will be overwritten by the `for` statements.
- the column letter should be `a[cols]`, not `a[num_cols]` as that will give you a value starting from the last column
- there is no reason to increment `num_cols` in your loop because it is used as the end of the range of the loop and changing it will have no effect on the loop
- there is no reason to increment `rows`, that is achieved by the `for` statement
- the range for the `rows` loop should be `(1, num_rows+1)` to have row numbers start at 1
- you need a `print()` in the `rows` loop to start a new line for each row

Putting all this together, you get:

```
num_rows = int(input('rows'))
num_cols = int(input('cols'))

a = list('abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz')

for rows in range(1, num_rows+1):
    for cols in range(num_cols):
        print('{}{}'.format(rows, a[cols]), end=' ')
    print()
```

For `num_rows = 3` and `num_cols = 4` this outputs:

```
1a 1b 1c 1d 
2a 2b 2c 2d 
3a 3b 3c 3d
```